# Omitting one particular nested folder while copying a folder

Tags: cp, file-copy, bsd

I know how to use the `cp` command to recursively (`-r`) copy nested folders while preserving (`-p`) file meta-data such as modification times:

```
cp -pr "/path/from" "path/to"
```

Is there a way to omit one particular folder nested at the first level deep, by name?

For example, a folder named `Photos` is being copied. I want to skip the `Dogs` folder nested within. I want everything but not `/Photos/Dogs` folder nor its contents.

I suppose I could let it copy, then delete. But that is inefficient. Is there a way no avoid the folder copy in the first place.

I am working on macOS Mojave currently, and FreeBSD 12 later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can fairly easily make a copy of a file structure while avoiding copying one or several of the subdirectories, but you would not do it with `cp`.

With `rsync`, you can exclude files and/or directories using an exclusion pattern.  In your case, it looks like you'd want to use

```
rsync -av --exclude='Photos/Dogs/' /path/from/ path/to
```

This would make `path/to` an exact copy of `/path/from` while avoiding any directory called `Dogs` at any path matching `Photos/Dogs`.  If you remove the trailing `/` on the source directory, you'll instead get `path/to/from` as an exact copy of the source folder.

The exclude pattern used would make `rsync` ignore any subdirectory called `Dogs` located in a directory called `Photos`, for example `/path/from/Photos/Dogs` and `/path/from/holidays/2013/Photos/Dogs`.  Using `--exclude=Dogs/` would exclude any subdirectory called `Dogs` regardless of what its parent directory is called, and using `--exclude=Dogs` would exclude anything (regardless of file type) that is called `Dogs`. To match only a `Photos/Dogs` directory *directly* under `/path/from`, use `--exclude='/Photos/Dogs/'`.

See the section called "INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES" in the `rsync` manual on your system.

The `-a` (`--archive`) option will make sure timestamps, permissions etc. are also copied, and also enable recursive copying.  The `-v` (`--verbose`) option enables verbose operation.

Add `-H` (`--hard-links`) if you want to preserve hard linking between names (again, see the `rsync` manual).